# GridLayout not showing up on frame when it should be

Tags: java, swing, function, button, layout

Right now it just shows the frame with the "solve" button, the text field, and the JLabel. When I press "solve" with a number in the text field, it is supposed to go through the NQueens model, figure out how many solutions there are, and show one solution on screen using a grid layout. But when I click solve, nothing actually happens. I have tried calling the repaint() and revalidate() methods for the view but those don't seem to be working.

The Solve button uses reflection to go to the controller to see what to do. Does anyone know what is going on? it is MVC style

Controller class:

```
package model;

public class Controller {
    private View myView;
    private NQueensModel myModel;
    private int int1, possibilities;
    public Controller()
    {
        myView = new View(this);

    }
    public void solve()
    {
        int1 = myView.getEntryInt();
        myView.doViewGrid();
        myModel = new NQueensModel(int1);
        myModel.solvePuzzle();
        possibilities = myModel.getPossibilities();
        myView.addButtons();
        myView.setPossibilitiesLabel(possibilities);
        myView.revalidate();
        myView.repaint();




    }

    public boolean[][] getMyBoard()
    {
        return myModel.getBoard();
    }


    /*public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
    }*/

}
```

View class

```
package model;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import model.ButtonListener;
import model.Controller;



import java.lang.reflect.Method;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class View extends JFrame {
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    private static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 250;
    private static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 250;

    private JButton solveButton;
    JPanel gridPanel;
    private JTextField text;
    private String entryNum;
    private int entryInt;
    private ButtonListener mySolveListener;
    private boolean[][] myBoard;
    private JButton buttons, emptyButtons;
    private JLabel possibilitiesLabel;
    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
    private static Controller myController;
    public View(Controller controller)
    {
        JPanel gridPanel;
        gridPanel = new JPanel();
        gridPanel.setBounds(100,100,400,400);
        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
        this.add(gridPanel);
        this.setTitle("NQueens");
        myController = controller;

        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
//      this.associateListeners();
        Container contentPane;
//      this.add(contentPane);
        this.setTitle("NQueens");

//      this.addWindowListener(new AWindowListener());
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);


        solveButton = new JButton("Solve");
        solveButton.setBounds(500,500,80,80);
        this.add(solveButton);

        text = new JTextField();
        text.setBounds(400,500,80,80);
        this.add(text);

        possibilitiesLabel = new JLabel("Possibilities: ");
        possibilitiesLabel.setBounds(240,500,80,80);
        this.add(possibilitiesLabel);


        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void setPossibilitiesLabel(int x)
    {
        possibilitiesLabel.setText("Possiblities: " + x);
    }
    public void doInt(){
        entryNum = text.getText();
        entryInt = Integer.parseInt(entryNum);
    }
    public int getEntryInt(){
        return entryInt;
    }
    public void addButtons()
    {
        myBoard = myController.getMyBoard();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getEntryInt(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0 ; j < this.getEntryInt(); j++)
            {


                if(myBoard[i][j]==true)
                {
                    buttons = new JButton("Q");
                    gridPanel.add(buttons);
                    this.setVisible(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    emptyButtons = new JButton(" ");
                    gridPanel.add(emptyButtons);
                    this.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void doViewGrid(){
        gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(this.getEntryInt(),this.getEntryInt()));
    }
      /**
     * Associates each component's listener with the controller
     * and the correct method to invoke when triggered.
     *
     * <pre>
     * pre:  the controller class has be instantiated
     * post: all listeners have been associated to the controller
     *       and the method it must invoke
     * </pre>
     */
    public void associateListeners()
    {
        String error;
        Class<? extends Controller> controllerClass;
        Method solveMethod,
               decrementMethod;
        Class<?>[] classArgs;
        Integer[] args;

        controllerClass = myController.getClass();

        error = null;
        solveMethod = null;
        decrementMethod = null;

        classArgs = new Class[1];
        args = new Integer[1];

        // Set argument types for method invokations
        try
        {
           classArgs[0] = Class.forName("java.lang.Integer");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException exception)
        {
           error = exception.toString();
           System.out.println(error);
        }

        // Associate method names with actual methods to be invoked
        try
        {
           solveMethod = controllerClass.getMethod("solve",classArgs);
           decrementMethod = controllerClass.getMethod("decrement",classArgs);        
        }

        catch(NoSuchMethodException exception)
        {
           error = exception.toString();
           System.out.println(error);
        }
        catch(SecurityException exception)
        {
           error = exception.toString();
           System.out.println(error);
        }

        // Set up listeners with actual argument values passed in
        // to methods

        args[0] = new Integer(200);
        mySolveListener 
               = new ButtonListener(myController, solveMethod, args);
//        myDecrementListener 
//               = new ButtonListener(myController, decrementMethod, args);
    }

}
```

Model

```
package model;

public class NQueensModel
{
    private int myNumsQueen;
    public int myPossibilities=0;
    private boolean[][] myBoard;
  //  private static NQueensModel myModel = new NQueensModel(5);

    public static void main (String[] args) {

//        System.out.println(myModel.solvePuzzle());
//        System.out.println(myModel.myPossibilities);
//        System.out.println(myModel.doIt(myModel.myPossibilities)); //you want this




       // System.out.println(myPossibilities);


    }
    public NQueensModel(int nQueens)
    {
        myNumsQueen = nQueens;
        myPossibilities=0;
        myBoard = new boolean[myNumsQueen][myNumsQueen];
    }
    public boolean solvePuzzle()
    {
//      return this.doIt(myModel.myPossibilities);
        return solvePuzzle(0);

    }
    private boolean solvePuzzle(int ncolumn)
    {
        if(ncolumn>myNumsQueen-1)
        {
            myPossibilities++;
//            return true;          
        }
        int i;       
        for( i =0; i<myNumsQueen;i++)
        {           
            if(this.isSafeMove(i, ncolumn)==true)
            {                
                this.placeQueen(i,ncolumn);
                if(this.solvePuzzle(ncolumn+1)==true)
                {   
                    return true;                 
                }
                this.removeQueen(i, ncolumn);
            }     

        }      
//        else if(myPossibilities>0)
//        {
//          return true;
//        }

        return false;

    }

    private boolean doIt(int county)
    {
        if(county>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
//    private int solveCount(int count, int col)
//    {
//      for(int j = 0 ; j<col; j++){
//          if(myModel.solvePuzzle(j)==true){
//               count++;
//          }
//          else if(myModel.solvePuzzle(j)==false){
//              return count;
//          }
//          else
//          {
//              for(int i =0 ; i<col;i++){
//                  count = solveCount(count, col+1);
//              }
//              return count;
//          }
//          return count;
//      }
//      return count;
//      
//    }
    private boolean isSafeMove(int row, int col)
    {
        if(row <0 || row>=myNumsQueen || col<0 || col>=myNumsQueen)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(this.checkLowerDiag(row, col)==true ||this.checkUpperDiag(row, col)==true ||this.checkLeft(row,col)==true)
         {
             return false;
         }
        else
        {

            return true;
        }


    }
    private boolean checkUpperDiag(int row, int col)
    {    
        if(row==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=row, j = col; i>=0 && j>=0; i--, j--)
            {
                if(myBoard[i][j]==true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean checkLowerDiag(int row, int col)
    {

        if(col==0 )
        {           
            return false;             
        }
        if(row==myNumsQueen-1){
            return false;
        }
        else
        {

            for(int i = row, j = col; i<myNumsQueen && j>=0;  i++, j--)
            {   
//              System.out.println("error" + i + " " + j );
                if(j>=myNumsQueen)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                else if(myBoard[i][j]==true)
                {
                    return true;

                }


            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    private boolean checkLeft(int row, int col)
    {
        if(col==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else 
        {
            for(int i = col; i>=0; i--)
            {

                if(i>=myNumsQueen)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                else if(myBoard[row][i]==true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
    private boolean placeQueen(int row, int col)
    {
        if(col>=myNumsQueen)
        {
            return false;
        }

        myBoard[row][col] = true;
        return true;
    }
    private boolean removeQueen(int row, int col)
    {
        myBoard[row][col] = false;
        return false;
    }
    public int getPossibilities(){
        return this.myPossibilities;
    }
    public boolean[][] getBoard()
    {
        return myBoard;
    }
//    public String toString()
//    {
//        
//    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are printing out the NoSuchMethodException, I assume you can see in your program output that your controller class does not have a solve(Integer) method.

You will be doing yourself a favor if you get rid of all reflection.  You don't need it, and errors like this are a big reason you shouldn't use it.  If you just wrote code that called the methods directly, the compiler would tell you about things like passing the wrong parameters to a method.

Here is the standard way to write a button listener:

```
solveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        myController.solve(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have to use reflection

Comment: An exception means "This method did not work, and you cannot continue as if it did work."  If you get a NoSuchMethodException, your code has a problem and you should exit your associateListeners method, preferably with `throw new RuntimeException(exception);`.  Hiding the exception only makes the problem harder to solve.  In your case, it is telling you that there is no solve(java.lang.Integer) method.